# What is the thing called that is located in this shower door frame?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I need help finding this part of a shower door. What is it called? It prevents water from going outside of the shower. Thanks

[image: this thing]

Answer (score 1):

That appears to be a seal on the edge of the door gutter/track.  From your photo we can't readily determine if that's the upper or lower edge, and whether it is the inside or outside edge.  It may make a difference when you attempt to identify the proper replacement part, assuming you don't have to replace the entire track.

Comment: Yes, its a seal on the edge of the door track. Its the upper-inside edge

Answer (score 0):

The flexible part that is attached to the door to prevent water from getting out is called a wipe.

Comment: Oh, it isnt attached to the door. Its attached to the shower door frame

Comment: Okay sorry.  So is the picture a U channel that the door slides in?   Those shouldn't typically need anything to stop water (they are one piece U shaped and have a drain hole in the bottom so any water drains back into the shower).  If its more of an LI with a gap, then maybe its sealed with a bead of caulking.

Comment: It is more of an L channel. There is a gap between the sliding door and the channel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. I found a substitute-ish for it. Its an auto car door trim. Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Please link to the product you used and describe how you installed it.

Comment: How I installed it: It is pretty simple on this one. Just push fit the molding to the edge. Link: http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/cowles-custom-door-molding-clear-black-or-chrome-3-8-in-0419325p.html